# Is there any way to run a VBScript file as a screen saver?

Tags: windows, vbscript, screensaver

Can you execute a VBS file as a screen saver? I have managed to rename `cmd.exe` to *.scr and this works, but I need to be able to run a VBS file as the screen saver if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

In Windows, screen savers (*.scr files) are a special type of executable (.exe) file. That is why renaming a program like `cmd.exe` to `cmd.scr` causes it to sort of "work" as a screen saver. In particular, screen savers respond to certain command line switches (or parameters), which is how the OS gets them to do things like show the configuration dialog or display a preview.

But you can't compile VBScript files into executables, so there's no way to make this trick work for them.

You might be able to migrate the VBScript code to a VB 6 application, which you could then compile into an executable and run as a screen saver, but I can't imagine that this would be worth the development time. If you're interested in such a thing (and can get your hands on an old copy of VB 6!), you can probably find several how-to guides online, like [this one](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/createing-visual-basic-screen-saver).

But I'm honestly having a hard time imagining why one would ever want to run a VBScript script as a screen saver, or what it would display on the screen. You don't have very much control over what gets displayed on the screen, and you can't call down to native Windows API functions from VBScript. You'd end up relying upon some external library, so you might as well just use that library in the first place.

Comment: What it would display on the screen? `MsgBox "Press OK to end screen saver."` +1

Comment: Thanks for the info, the reason I wanted to run a vbscript was that the vbscript would silently open a batch file, e.g. run commands when the user is away so the pc performance doesn't affect them, but no worries, cheers!

Comment: @Bali: Although it's certainly a novel one, that's probably not the best use of a screen saver. You should create a scheduled task using the Windows Task Scheduler, and set it to run when the computer is idle. You can configure it to start a batch file or VBScript file if you want. That sounds like a much better option to me.

Comment: @Cody: Slight correction, you actually can compile vbscript to exe, but I agree the OP is going about the task in a roundabout way.

Comment: @unreal: No, you cannot. There are some third party utilities that essentially wrap the VBS file in a self-extracting executable. But that doesn't count as *compilation*. Just as important, this is third-party software you have to depend on, not something that's provided with the VBScript engine, or even anything that has anything to do with VBScript. Regardless of your pseudo-compilation mechanism, the file must be converted back into a VBS file so that the system's VBScript engine can execute it.

Comment: @Cody: Well yeah it is an interpreted language, and yeah some third party app has to wrap the code, but it is a bit disingenuous to say you absolutely cannot make a vbs into an executable when that is not in fact the case.  You could of course debate the semantics over whether it is actually compiled or just wrapped, but that's a bit moot.  In either case, I'm still in agreement, the OP is going about it entirely wrong and the scheduled task is a much better route to go.

Comment: Cheers guys, yeah I think I will go down the scheduled task route. This was intended to be more of a is it possible task rather than a actual issue i was having but nice to know if it can be done or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a batch file that starts your vb script:
CD "%SystemRoot%\System32"
Start /Wait Wscript.exe "c:\program files\myscript.vbs"
Exit

Then compile the batch to exe, rename the exe to scr.

Comment: Compile the batch to EXE how, exactly? That's an interesting idea, but it's not something that you can just assume is commonly known.